# How get all organization name in xero api for private app?

Tags: php, api, xero-api

I am new in API integration

Here is my request code-

```
<li><a href="?organization=1">Organization</a></li>
 if (isset($_REQUEST['organisation'])) {
       $response = $XeroOAuth->request('GET', $XeroOAuth->url('Organisation', 'core'), array('page' => 0));
       if ($XeroOAuth->response['code'] == 200) {
           $organisation = $XeroOAuth->parseResponse($XeroOAuth->response['response'], $XeroOAuth->response['format']); 
       print_r($organisation);
           echo "Organisation name: " . $organisation->Organisations[0]->Organisation->Name;
       } else {
           outputError($XeroOAuth);
       }
   }
```

Here is output code-

```
Organisation name: Cadeo
```

I want to get all organization name?

Answer (score 2):

Organisation object in Xero has various properties. **'Name'** is one of them.
What you might be referring to is full name or Registered name. It can be accessed through **"LegalName"** property.

For all the properties or values you can get for Organisation, check the following [documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/organisation/)

Answer (score 1):

A private app can only be connected to one organisation in Xero.

If you want to connect your app to more than one organisation, you will need to create a public (or partner) app.